# Routing is Not Calling Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/navbar.component";
import HomePage from "./pages/homePage/HomePage.component";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/footer.component";
import BlogPage from "./pages/blogPage/BlogPage.component";
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="./BlogPage" component={BlogPage} />
          <Route exact path="./" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run the app the home component loads without any trouble, but it only loads `Navbar` and `Footer` Components, Clearly I am doing something wrong but I haven't been able to figure out what.

Comment: Take the "." out of each route. It's not allowing the path to match the URL. React router doesn't use relative paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path you are using in `Route` is the path what you see in the browser url. You dont need dot before the path So,

Replace

```
<Route exact path="./BlogPage" component={BlogPage} />
<Route exact path="./" component={HomePage} />
```

by this

```
<Route exact path="/BlogPage" component={BlogPage} />
 <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
```